# How to use maven to unpack resource folder when .jar is ran

Tags: java, maven, build, jar

I have a project that was written entirely independent of Maven, and now that we need to build a distributable .jar, we can't get the resource files packed in the .jar correctly.

The resource files are basically a bunch of .csv files that the user needs to have already setup, but can modify in the future.

I want the program to run like so:

1. Launch program.jar
2. Reads the resource files in the resource folder, but if it doesn't exist, make the files/folder.
3. Program runs, calls resource files
4. Program ends, users are free to modify .csv files.

We've tried including the resource files (in another directory) in the list of dependencies when the program is built, but it doesn't work when an outside user runs it. The code references the filepath multiple times (C:\commonfolder\resources\alltheCSVfiles)

I'm using java JDK 10.0.01, and intelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to read resources at runtime from the file system of the user.

This cannot be done with Maven because Maven is only a build tool. It may take resources during the build and put them into your jar, but this seems to be different from your use case.